# C sharp continue

Tags: c#

instead of using the code "continue;" what could you use? I am trying to implement this code without using the code continue.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {


            if (frequencyCount[i] > max)
            {
                flag = false;
                index = i;
                max = frequencyCount[i];

                continue; //skips the iteration the for loop so dont go round again 

            }

            if (frequencyCount[i] == max)
            {
                flag = true;

            }
```

Comment: Is there anything else after that second `if`? The loop is incomplete.

Comment: `else` after first `if`.

Comment: Make the second if `else if` so it is skipped if you hit the first `if` Assuming this is the entirety of your loop. Though I'd have to ask *why* you're making this strange requirement to begin with.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you expect the program to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the continue, you can put the rest of the code in the else statement. By example:

```
if (frequencyCount[i] > max) {
 ......do your instructions and do not add continue
} else { //this will only be executed when the if is false
  ....the other instructions 
}
```

Let me know if this helps you, otherwise try to add the idea of your code or the code complete to allow better answers.